# How do I map screen coordinates to world coordinates

Tags: android, image, opencv, image-processing, opengl-es

I am using a stereoscopic image with two cameras. I have the baseline and focal length of the camera with depth information. Using the xs,ys screen coordinates and the depth data, is it possible to map x,y to the world coordinates. Basically I want to measure the actual size of the object using pixels on the image.